# ASPdotnetstorefront menu won't update with changes made in menudata.xml

Tags: asp.net

I am setting up an ASP.netstorefront site and when I edit the menudata.xml, no changes appear. No matter what I do I can not get it to update the menu on the website. Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured out the problem. In this build, the menu is pulled from topnav.xml.config, not the typical menudata.xml that the manual says the menu comes form.

Answer (score 1):

what version are you using?

With ASPDSNF you can find that there are duplicate xml packages. There is a xmlpackages folder within the root /web folder but you may find that copying your xml packages to the relevant App_Templates/Skin1/XmlPackages folder may work

If you are on Multistore then each store would have Skin1, Skin2 etc..